# Null String value to hardcode value

Tags: apex, class, string

I have below piece code where I want to assign 'No Value' to the string (Oldvalue) if it is Null. I have tried it by several approaches like (String.isblank etc), but not getting desired output. Can someone please help?

Class code snippet:

```
if(oldValue==null)
    oldvalue='No Value';

system.debug('Oldvalue@'+oldvalue);

aht.Alert_Text_vod__c = alts.Alert_Text_abv__c + ' ' + oldvalue +' to ' + newValue;
```

Comment: What is the context that you're getting oldValue from? Might be better to have a little more of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you could be doing wrong, but if I run the following code in an execute anonymous window it appears to do what you're after.

It could be that your string has been initialized which means it's a blank string rather than null.  This is why it's important to use functions like `isBlank()` rather than checking for nulls.

```
String oldValue;

if(String.isBlank(oldValue)) {
    oldValue = 'No Value';
}

System.debug('oldValue: ' + oldValue);
```

Or you can do the assignment with a ternary operator:

```
String oldValue;

oldValue = String.isBlank(oldValue) ? 'No Value' : oldValue;

System.debug('oldValue: ' + oldValue);
```

Does this help?